# ASP.NET MVC User role in Angular2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I'am new in Angular2 and now I would like to change my website to Angular2,and in cshtml file we can show specific HTML with razor like:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    <span>Admin can see here only!</span>
}
```

And now in Angular2 there's no cshtml,my choice is use AJAX to get the role and put in a variable or LocalStorage,is there any better practice?thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.
In Angular 2 you could use `if conditions` as well but in a different manner.
For example:

```
<div *ngIf="isAdmin" > Admin can see here only! </div>
```

This means that this div will be shown only when the `isAdmin` value is true.
And the is admin true should be set on your `.ts` (typescript) file where you actually will have the app logic.

Comment: I am new to Angular and I have a question which might be stupid (I still have a lot of Angular to learn). If you use this approach can't the user change "isAdmin" to true by javascript?

Comment: First of all no question is stupid. Only the answers can be stupid. :)
The whole idea behind using this kind of approach is that you get rid of raw JavaScript so you use Typescript bindings.